# Is there any automated online service for making white board animation?

Tags: video, animation

I want to know is there any website or software available to make white board animation as following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video you showed is simply a stop motion video, not an animation.

So you aren't going to be able to simply send a jpg off somewhere and have it come back as a video.

There are plenty of video houses that will happily make you a video like this, but it is time consuming. Usually they video the entire process of drawing the art, then cut out frames - to ensure they keep in important key frames.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have seen this kind of marketing videos so many places. So I curious to know that is this make from service like goanimate.com . So I asked

Answer (score 0):

[**VideoScribe**](http://www.videoscribe.co/) : Open a svg > select a hand [optional]. Thats all. Your animation is ready. But you cant provide motion animation as you can do in Flash. If you want to give painting, sketching, zooming in/out, camera move or erasing effect you can do all.

[**PowToon**](http://www.powtoon.com/) : Good for animated presentations where you don't want instant sketching effect