# how to make video scribe or whiteboard animation?

Tags: video

I want to know how to make video scribe or whiteboard animation?

Example:

Please suggest me some tools

Comment: Related... http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/is-there-any-automated-online-service-for-making-white-board-animation?rq=1

Comment: also related... http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/7178/whiteboard-animation-how-to-zoom-and-draw-a-motion

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways.  You can do it with flash, you can do it with After Effects (probably the most popular).  If you want to do it cheap, you can do it with a tripod and a still camera and just do a lot of stop motion.

Comment: Stop motion, or just speed the video up a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with Powtoon. It's free. They have whiteboard writing effects for text, but to get images drawn, you might need to use a pro app.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Yes, the OP does ask for names of tools, but without some explanation of how to use the tool it is of limited benefit.